# HTML Input tag checked attribute can not see in the debug element while default value is false

Tags: html, reactjs

**Example**

```
import {useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  return (
      <div style={{width: "100vw", height: "100vh"}}>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={!!checked} onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)} />
      </div>
  );
}
```

- If you click these checkbox, the check attribute can never seen in the debug console, Is that right?
- default checked set to false

[image]

- default checked set to true will always show the checked attibute.

[image]

Comment: Adjusting a checkbox's values in HTML does not toggle the attribute, it just changes the value (`.checked`, really) and dispatches an event. The attribute only represents the initial state here.

Comment: OK I have seen components library has no such attribute as well.

Comment: You still need the attribute if you want the checkbox to initially be checked, though!

Comment: Yeah, I have pinned the two scenario above. If It is initially checked, we can see the `checked` attribute